# How to move to the next column in my Access database from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Right now I am trying to export data from Excel to Access with VBA.

```
 rst("2k2").Value = sProduct
```

This is an example of what I currently use which is putting the value sProduct into the column in Access called "2k2". How would I move to the next column in Access and put a value in that column? Besides the obvious using the name of that column.

Thanks!

Comment: Use that column name in place of `2K2`.

Comment: That's what i am trying to avoid doing haha its in the last sentence. I have alot of columns I would like to be able to achieve this with a loop and not manually do every single one of them

Comment: *Besides the obvious using the name of that column* - without more information about your schema, the shape of the source and destination tables, we can't do much more than guesswork. How many rows are we talking about? One? Then send a parameterized `INSERT` query over the connection and don't bother with a recordset.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon what do you need to know? its just a table in access and putting a value in an excel to a particular column

Comment: If rst is a recordset you could loop through the columns using the [fields collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/jj249154.aspx)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - If someone provides a looping solution through different columns, returning the name after `2k2` the OP would be happy in 99% of the cases.  And the rest of us should hope that this is not a software supporting a nuclear power station...

Comment: use the `.fields` collection of the recordset, or `.openschema` to look at the table schema.

Comment: @Vityata call me a heretic, but for one-time imports from Excel to SQL Server I tend to write a `="INSERT INTO dbo.Table1(foo, bar, baz) VALUES (" & A2 & "," & B2 & ",'" & C2 & "')"` formula, fill it down, copy & paste into SSMS, fix the single quotes and run & move on.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - as far as it is not a nuclear power station or similar...

Comment: Question to the TO: How do you define next column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the fields to a variable and cycle through them.

```
Dim fld as DAO.Field

for each fld in rst.fields
    'Do some stuff
next
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** As mentioned in the comments, do not use this code in a production environment. Use it only for a DB, which you are using for a school project or anything similar. Databases are really different than an Excel Spreadsheet and the position of the columns is not always constant.

Having said this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetColumnNameAfter(columnName As String) As String

    Dim cnLogs As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rsHeaders As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rsData As New ADODB.Recordset    
    Dim myCounter As Long
    Dim myConn As String
    Dim nameFound As Boolean

    myConn = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;"
    myConn = myConn & "Initial Catalog=Blog;Trusted_Connection=yes;timeout=30;"
    cnLogs.Open myConn

    With rsHeaders
        .ActiveConnection = cnLogs
        .Open "SELECT * FROM syscolumns WHERE id=OBJECT_ID('Posts')"

        Do While Not rsHeaders.EOF
            'Printing is fun...
            'Debug.Print rsHeaders(0)

            If nameFound Then
                GetColumnNameAfter = rsHeaders(0)
                Exit Function
            End If

            If columnName = rsHeaders(0) Then nameFound = True
            myCounter = myCounter + 1
            rsHeaders.MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With

End Function
```

In the `strConn` change the Initial Catalog to your DB and the DB Table Posts here `OBJECT_ID('Posts')"` to your DB table. Then the function will return the `String` name of the column after the the one you have provided as a parameter.

The code loops through the Headers of a table, named "Posts", which is in a DB named `Blog`. Once it finds a header, named `columnName`, it sets the `nameFound` to `True` and returns the Name of the next column.

Once you know the name of the "Next" column, you can use the same logic as in your question.